# Qiwi - подключение без комиссии

Tags: qiwi

Сейчас работаю с QiWi через их магазин, но там комиссия 3%.

Увидел на одном сайте, что юзер оплачивает через киви без комиссии, ему выдают номер на который нужно перевести деньги, с уникальным примечанием, и все. 
Комиссии 0, все довольны.

Как это может работать? В обычном киви ( не в магазине ishop ) не нашел никаких http оповещений, как это делается обычно...

Может кто то подскажет, может они почту парсят, или еще как то ?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в техподдержку QIWI.

Comment: Если это некая "хитрость", то врядли они подскажут.

Comment: Ну раз на номер перевод может киви туда sms присылает и они эти sms обрабатывают

Comment: Возможно и из смс считывают, как вариант..

Comment: А других вариантов нет, или вы организация и у вас договор с киви (кстати 3% это еще мало) и они по этому договору на шлюз сообщают. либо у вас киви-кошелек и вы частное лицо и тогда никаких шлюзов ибо у частных лиц их не бывает. И кстати, если у меня сайт попросит перевести на   кошелек я уйду с него и никогда не вернусь